# Java, сортировка списка строк в прямом и обратном порядке

Tags: java, сортировка, arraylist

Ести список строк: 
"Иванов"
"Иванкин"
"Ивченко"
"Лавриенко"
"Лавочкин"
"Абрамов"
"Абдулов"
"Акрин"
"Циганов"

Их необходимо отсортировать так, что бы начало строки сортировалось по naturalOrder, а оставшаяся часть - в обратном порядке, т.е. отсортированный список должен иметь следующую последовательность:
"Акрин"
"Абрамов"
"Абдулов"
"Ивченко"
"Иванов"
"Иванкин"
"Лавриенко"
"Лавочкин"
"Циганов"

Как я понимаю надо использовать 2 компаратора, но как это реализовать в коде не имею представления.

Comment: Вам нужен один правильно написанный компаратор.

Comment: В смысле? Сортировка по первым символам строки - по нарастанию, а затем, по остальным символам, кроме первого - по убыванию? Регулярные выражения.

Comment: Начало строки - первая буква?

Comment: @Anton Sorokin Начало строки первая буква, если среди строк есть совпадения по первой букве, то продолжается стравнение, пока буквы не окажутся !=. Если != то сортировать в обратном порядке.

Comment: Если ответ решает вашу проблему, примите его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Иванов", "Иванкин", "Ивченко", "Лавриенко", "Лавочкин", "Абрамов", "Абдулов", "Акрин", "Циганов");
strings.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    int firstCharComparison = o1.charAt(0) - o2.charAt(0);
    int secondCharComparison = -String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(o1.substring(1), o2.substring(1));
    return firstCharComparison != 0 ? firstCharComparison : secondCharComparison;
});
System.out.println(strings);
```

`firstCharComparison` - сравнение первых символов

`secondCharComparison` - используем компаратор из стандартной java библиотеки который сравнивает строчки после первого символа. перед ним стоит `-` так как нам нужен обратный порядок.

Возвращаем по приоритету. Если результат сравнения по первому символу не видит отличий, возвращаем результат по второму. Иначе по первому.

**Внимание!** Для простоты кода я не включил проверки на null, длину строк и регистр первого символа. Это оставил на вас)

Comment: ну и `secondCharComparison` имеет смысл вообще считать только если `firstCharComparison == 0`

Comment: @tym32167 Тоже верно